# Getting "Invalid Column Name " Sql Exception in the following code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to pass both Column name and the Value to be checked in the code at runtime. However I am getting an "Invalid Column Name   " exception.
The code is as follows :

```
string temp = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Sagar\\Documents\\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee Where @field = Sagar", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
//com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", temp);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Without your database/table schema there is no way anyone can answer this, aside from repeating the error message as @ThorstenDittmar has

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can make your code this way, which works perfectly:

```
"Select * from Employee Where "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()+" =
'Sagar'" – Vidhya Sagar Reddy
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I don't know why it didn't work earlier when i tried it. Maybe because i added the @ in the AddWithValue function.

Comment: @sagarwadhwa1: No, that is not the reason! Did you read my answer and the comments?

Comment: This is not a good way to build queries, very prone to SQL Injections.

Answer (score 14):

The message says that there is no column named 'Sagar' in the table. Is there such a column? Things would be easier if you showed us the table schema instead of having us guess from the error message.

---

**It is not possible to parameterize column names using `SqlParameter` in C#. This has been discussed here multiple times.**

What's happening with the query the way `Vidhya Sagar Reddy` is doing it, is the following. He assumes that the following query

```
Select * from Employee Where @field = 'Sagar'
```

is replaced by this query when setting `"Name"` as the value for the `@field` parameter:

```
Select * from Employee Where Name = 'Sagar'
```

**This, however, is wrong!** What's happening is that the `@field` parameter is replaced as follows:

```
Select * from Employee Where 'Name' = 'Sagar'
```

This returns no results, as the `WHERE` clause is always `false`. Of course, if you use the field name `Sagar`, this akways returns `true`, as the statement then reads:

```
Select * from Employee Where 'Sagar' = 'Sagar'
```

---

Here's an easy test to prove what I've said above. Use the following statement to set the `@field` parameter (supposed, there's no column named `eirghoerihgoh` in the table):

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", "eirghoerihgoh");
```

If the query executes correctly (maybe not returning any results), the above is correct. If it was not correct, an exception should be thrown about the `eirghoerihgoh` column not being present.

---

Thank you `Vidhya Sagar Reddy` for proving my point. By using this line

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", "eirghoerihgoh");
```

you say you didn't get any results, but you also didn't get an exception. However, if the statement really had been changed to

```
Select * from Employee Where eirghoerihgoh = 'Sagar'
```

there had to be an exception saying that there was no column named `eirghoerihgoh`. As you didn't get that exception, there's only one possible explanation: The statement was changed to

```
Select * from Employee Where 'eirghoerihgoh' = 'Sagar'
```

and this executes, but doesn't return results, as the condition is always `false`.

Comment: No it is not - at least not in your query. String values need to be enclosed in single quotes ('). That's why you get the error. You can *not parameterize the column name*!

Comment: No you can not. You're testing the wrong way. The query you're creating above reads `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE 'Sagar' = 'Sagar'`. The `WHERE` condition here is **always true**, so it returns all rows. If you want a real test, select a column from your combo box that does not contain the string `Sagar`.

Comment: I don't need to check this, because I know that it is not possible - you're testing it wrong! Add another column to the table named `Test`, put the value `Sagar` into it for all records and then add it to your combo box. Select it from the combo box and execute your query. The query will then read `SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE 'Test' = 'Sagar'` - you will get **NO** results, even though you think you should, and that's where you're wrong!!

Comment: the query would become SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Test = 'Sagar' if parameterized command statement is used..!!!!

Comment: No, it does not. Have you tried what I suggest? Just to make sure you understand: Set the parameter `@field` to a column name **that you are sure DOESN'T** exist! If the query executes correctly (but maybe doesn't return any records), I'm right. If the query throws an exception about a missing column named after the text you put in the parameter, you may be right if you can prove to the world that you actually did as I said. Use this line: `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", "eirghoerihgoh");`

Comment: Thats not throwing me an exception but thats not even fetching the records too...!!!

Comment: Right. **That's exactly what I'm saying**. Your're wrong, I'm right, because the statement is `SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE 'eirghoerihgoh' = 'Sagar'`. This does execute, but doesn't return records as the `WHERE` clause is always `false`. If you were right (which you are not), you should get an exception about the column `eirghoerihgoh` not existing. As you do not get this exception, either the column `eirghoerihgoh` exists in the table (which I assume is not the case) or the statement **CAN NOT BE** `SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE eirghoerihgoh = 'Sagar'`. Case closed.

Comment: @VidhyaSagarReddy : Turns out Thorsten is correct. I am not able to parameterize the Column Name.

Comment: But thats not even throwing me an error; I've observed the statement throught SQL Profilferl, which i found it like: exec sp_executesql N'select * from AddressBook where @ddl= ''SGAR''',N'@ddl nvarchar(8)',@ddl=N'FirstName'  I think we need to dig into this deeply to get.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't get what's happening here! Assuming you are right, then providing `eogihöeoihgöobugöoaweubr` for the `@ddl` parameter (in your example) you must (*must*, **must**) get an exception saying that the column doesn't exist! Don't you understand why? There's no need to "dig into this deeply" - you simply didn't understand how parameterized queries work. That's all. Even your SQL Profiler tells you so. It says, `@ddl` is a `NVARCHAR(8)` and the value is `'FirstName'`. So wherever it finds `@ddl`, it puts `'FirstName'`, so it's `SELECT ... WHERE 'FirstName' = 'SGAR'`.

Comment: @VidhyaSagarReddy Thorsten dittmar is right,this is how the paramaterized queries work.so better not to debate :)

Comment: Yeah; but i've even said: Instead you can make your code this way, which works perfectly: "Select * from Employee Where "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()+" = 'Sagar'" – Vidhya Sagar Reddy

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is quite simple, the value that are to be specified in SQL should be in single quotes and this is a simple mistake by the way..!!!!

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee Where @field = 'Sagar'", con);
```

And even change the parameter to "field" in the following line and not "@field"..!!

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("field", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

This is working..>!!!!

Comment: I doubt that, because **you can not parameterize the column name**! I bet you're getting *all rows* now if you set `@field` to `'Sagar'`, as then the query is `SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE 'Sagar' = 'Sagar'` and that returns all rows. Easy test: Select another item from your combo box, which doesn't read "Sagar" - I bet you get no rows.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar : Is there any way I can pass the Column Name and select it dynamically during runtime ? Maybe through Dynamic SQL ? My method is taking both of them as row values.

Comment: Instead you can make your code this way, which works perfectly: "Select * from Employee Where "+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()+"  = 'Sagar'"

Comment: Yes, concatenating the statement is a solution. However, you need to be aware of the fact that you might open yourself to SQL injections.